# Ringing noise overpowering voice / Recording audio with Max 9814 microphone on Raspberry pi pico using ADC Pin / Circuitpython

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi-pico, adc, adafruit-circuitpython

I am working on a project where I record 5 seconds of audio and store it as a wave file onto an sd card. I want to be able to play the wave file through a speaker that I have connected to the pico board, which is why I trying to find a fix without the use of audio editing software.

I am able to record and play the audio, however the voice in the audio is distorted and is also very hard to hear as there is a loud ringing noise throughout the recording.

With a sample rate of 22050Hz, I have read the microphone ADC.value() multiplied it by 3.3V/65535, as the ADC value is given as a 16 bit number. I also tried dividing the voltage by 4096, which is the value I am supposed to use because the pico board is 12 bit.

Trying both of these have both resulted in the ringing sound still playing in the audio.

I am extremely new to the microcontroller world and I don't have that great of an understanding of how sound capture works with microphones.

**Am I doing something wrong or is there anything I can do to improve the quality of the recording without the use of audio editing software? **

Comment: You ask question that we can't answer, we have no idea what your circuit/schematic looks like? how do you convert the capture ADC and where you feed the data to and convert it back to audio? and you didn't show us a single line of code...